# How to return only ceratin columns in a hibernate query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I want to return certain selected columns from multiple tables in my `hibernate` query. I can do this but it returns as an Object type which I seemingly can do nothing with.

This is my query

```
public static synchronized List<TaskInstanceLineItem> getOpenTasks() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<TaskInstanceLineItem> list = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ti.taskComponents.task.name, ti.Id, ti.status FROM TaskInstance ti"
                + " INNER JOIN ti.taskComponents.task WHERE ti.taskComponents.live=true");
        list = query.list();
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

And I have created a class `TaskInstanceLineItem` which has the fields `name`, `id` and `status`, `getters` and `setters` and a `constuctor`. What further things do I need to do so that `Hibernate` will return this query inside this `TaskInstanceLineItem` object rather than just as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instances of TaskInstanceLineItem from HQL. You must create an constructor using class's fields.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT new TaskInstanceLineItem(ti.taskComponents.task.name, ti.Id, ti.status) FROM TaskInstance ti"
            + " INNER JOIN ti.taskComponents.task WHERE ti.taskComponents.live=true"
```

Comment: Any idea how I can build in the DISTINCT part now though?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constructor on your class that receives the fields you want to retrieve as parameters:

```
public class TaskInstance {
    public TaskInstance(Integer field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1; this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

Then you create the query like this:

```
select new TaskInstance(field1, field2) from TaskInstance inner join......
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly, Any idea how I can build in the DISTINCT part now though?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String SQL = ".."; //same SQL as you had before
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(SQL); //no entity mapping
query.setParameter("idContact", 9293L);
Object string = query.getSingleResult();
System.out.println(string);
```